# Adding two dynamic columns in the table through stored procedure and these columns must have data based on condition

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add two dynamic columns `HeaderText` and `IsShowHeader` to my table through a stored procedure.

In the first column, the first row must have text as `Header1` and after 8 rows text must be `Header2`, then again after 8 rows text must be `Header3` and so on.

In the second column value must be 1, and next 8 rows must have 0, the 9th row value must be 1 again, then the next 8 rows must have 0 like this...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SkipRow]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT   RID
            ,FirstName
            ,LastName                   
            ,(CASE WHEN X.[Row#]%9=0 And [X].[Row#]=0 THEN 1 ELSE 
                           0 END)As IsShowHeader        
            ,(COUNT(*) OVER ()) as TotalRows FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RID) AS [Row#] 
    FROM Mytable1 WITH(NOLOCK)
    )X 
End
```

Output:

```
           HeaderText                IsShowHeader
1            Header1                    1
2             Null                      0
3             Null                      0
4             Null                      0
5             Null                      0
6             Null                      0
7             Null                      0
8             Null                      0
9             Null                      0
10           Header2                    1
11            Null                      0
12            Null                      0
13            Null                      0
14            Null                      0
15            Null                      0
16            Null                      0
17            Null                      0
18            Null                      0
19           Header3                    1
```

Comment: Show the sample data! Is that last table is your expected output?

Comment: yes,that's Expected Output

Comment: sample data from `Mytable1` table/

Comment: unless you open your sql server for us so we can query the data in `Mytable1` ourself, you should add the content of table `Mytable1` that leads to this expected outcome to your question. I assume the first is not an option off course

Comment: In the Table "Mytable1" I have some Random Columns,But Now the Requirement is to add another two dynamic columns in "Mytable1" and those columns must have the values,that i have shown as output.

Comment: if all we get is `random columns` then how can we help you ? Help us help you and show us some sample data

Comment: I have Mentioned two columns as "First Name" and "LastName" thats the column i hav in "Mytable1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have the `[Row#]`, use the `modulus` operator `%` to get every 9 rows

```
HeaderText   = case when ([Row#] - 1) % 9 = 0 
                    then 'Header' + convert(varchar(10), ([Row#] - 1) / 9 + 1)
                    end,
IsShowHeader = case when ([Row#] - 1) % 9 = 0 
                    then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT M.id,
       M.HeaderText,
       CASE WHEN M.HeaderText IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsShowHeader
FROM
(
    SELECT P.id,
           CASE
               WHEN P.HeaderText IS NOT NULL THEN
                   P.HeaderText + CAST(P.IndexNumber AS VARCHAR(10))
               ELSE
                   NULL
           END AS HeaderText
    FROM
    (
        SELECT K.id,
               HeaderText,
               COUNT(K.HeaderText) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS IndexNumber
        FROM
        (
            SELECT id,
                   CASE
                       WHEN (id - 1) % 9 = 0 THEN 'Header' ELSE NULL
                   END AS HeaderText
            FROM dbo.test
        ) AS K
    ) AS P
) AS M;
```

I have illustrate the scenario step by step, however you can rewrite it in a simple way like the answer that [@Squirrel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662201/1666800) posted.